# Fortigate automation with perl or python

Tags: python, perl, ssh, fabric, rex

**Goal**
I'm trying to automate a fortigate configuration change for a couple dozen routers and am not winning. Have tried Python's paramiko library, Python fabric and Perl's expect and Rex interfaces/libraries.

**Other info**
* Routers: Fortigate 60D 
* Firmware: v5.0,build0252 (GA Patch 5)
* SSH enabled: True

I can log in over SSH and run these commands manually!

I used the perl expect library with Fortigate 60B's in the past but it no longer works. Before I share the code I want to ask:

Is there some new feature in Fortigate's that prevents this type of automation?

A simple and harmless command to test [ list current dhcp leases ]:

```
execute dhcp lease-list wifi
```

**Code**
Perl/Expect:

```
my $timeout = 10; 

$ssh->expect($timeout, [ qr/password: /i ]); 
$ssh->send("$passwd\r\n"); 
$ssh->expect($timeout, [ qr/#/i ]); 
$ssh->send("execute dhcp lease-list wifi\r"); 
$ssh->expect($timeout, [ qr/#/i ]); 
$ssh->send("exit\r"); 

$ssh->soft_close();
```

Output: none

Perl/Rex:

```
desc "List all dhcp leases";
task "leases", group => "forti", sub {
    my $output = run "execute dhcp lease-list wifi";
    say $output;
};
```

Output:

```
[2014-02-11 13:14:48] (30011) - INFO - Running task: leases
[2014-02-11 13:14:48] (30022) - INFO - Connecting to 10.10.10.2 (admin)
[2014-02-11 13:14:49] (30022) - INFO - Connected to 10.10.10.2, trying to authenticate.
Fortigate # Unknown action 0

Fortigate #
```

Python/paramiko:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.10.10.2',username='fake_root',password='fake_pass') 
stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh.exec_command("execute dhcp lease-list wifi")
stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

Output: none

Python/Fabric:

```
def view_dhcp_leases():
        print("Viewing dhcp leases")
        run("execute dhcp lease-list wifi")
```

Output:

```
[10.10.10.2] Executing task 'view_dhcp_leases'
Viewing dhcp leases
[10.10.10.2] run: execute dhcp lease-list wifi
[10.10.10.2] out: Fortigate # Unknown action 0
[10.10.10.2] out: 
[10.10.10.2] out: Fortigate # 

Done.
Disconnecting from 10.10.10.2 ... done.
```

**Conclusions ...so far**

`Unknown action 0` means, "I don't know this command [ in this context ]". This command ***can*** be run manually at the first prompt. Also, as you can see in the fabric and rex examples: it ***does*** authenticate and connect! I conclude that this is by design for security reasons ...and more likely to sell their proprietary management crap.

Comment: You may be affected by the issue described [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#FAQ)!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on a FortiNet Mail Appliance.

```
from Exscript.util.interact import Account
from Exscript.protocols import SSH2
account = Account('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
conn = SSH2()
conn.connect('IP')
conn.login(account)
conn.execute('COMMAND')
conn.send('exit \r')
conn.close()
```

https://github.com/knipknap/exscript

Answer (score 2):

The following script worked for me against a FortiGate (5.2.4) with Python/Paramiko:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('1.1.1.254',username='admin',password='password')
stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh.exec_command("get system status")
type(stdin)
stdout.readlines()
```

Andy

Comment: have you ever tried to run paraniko agains 5.2.5 or upwards? looks like it's broken since 5.2.5 (see https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/687)

Comment: When I try this I get `action not supported` from a Fortimail server

Answer (score 1):

I have 60B.

Please try to run this command from linux terminal.

If you don't have sshpass - you can install it.

sshpass -p 'adminpassword' ssh ip_of_fw -l admin  execute dhcp lease-list

Comment: sshpass does not work either. With the -V option it just gives the license then exits.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use fabric to run commands on fortigates you need to disable the shell wrapping used by fabric when connecting via SSH:

```
from fabric.api import run

def get_sys():
   run("get sys status",shell=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Youc can upgrade an OS version and then use API with P